# Select form, write selected item to database

Tags: forms

I'm using Drupal 7 and Form API.

My Problem:

I want to load rows from my Database and put them in a Select Form(Form API). After this form is submitted I want to write the selected option in my database.

The first step works fine but I don't know how to get the selected option for writing it into my database.

Load values from database:

```
$result = db_select('color', 'c')
->fields('c', array('ID', 'color', 'name')

->execute()

foreach($result as $row) {
     $options = $row->color . ' ' .$row->name; 
}
```

Add options to form:

```
 $form['colors'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#options' => $options,
 );
```

When form is submited:

```
db_insert() //Add ID of selected item to database
```

How do I get the ID of the selected color? The options of this select form is a name combination(color+name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a small error in your code, $options should be an array. Moreover, if you add a key=>value pair for each option, you can get the key of the selected option in the form_submit function. Here is what your foreach could look like:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
  $options[$row->ID] = $row->color . ' ' .$row->name; 
}
```

and in your submit function you can grab the ID of the selected option like this:

```
$color_id = $form_state['values']['color'];
```

Good luck!